# Get Field Names from database table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

In this case, I need to get the Field Name from the table :

this  is my static model

```
  <?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class Act_admin extends Model
{
    static function showCust(){
        $query = DB::table("dummy_db.customer")->select("*")->paginate(10);
        $FieldNames = Schema::getColumnListing($query);
        dd($FieldNames);

      // return $data;
    }
}
```

and the result just:

```
[]
```

Thanks before.

Comment: You must pass table name in function

Answer (score 0):

Pass table_name instead of $query in `getColumnListing()` function and it will works:-

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class Act_admin extends Model
{
    static function showCust(){
        $table_name = dummy_db.customer;
        $field_names = Schema::getColumnListing($table_name);
        dd($field_names);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get columns by this code

```
Public function getsomecolumns ($table)
{
Return DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing($able);
}
```

Or you can replace return to this method

```
Return Schema::getColumnlisting($table);
```